# How to check newly generated logfile on a folder path

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a simple script wherein I wanted to check if a log contains a specific string and give me an output if it contains the string or not. However the logfile gets updated daily and I wanted to check the most recent file. Is there a command I can add to my script to get the output I needed?. Or is there other way I can do this without using Select-String?.

```
$SEL = Select-String -Path Pathfile.LOG -Pattern "String"
if ($SEL -ne $null)
{
    echo Contains String
}
else
{
    echo Not Contains String
}}
```

Comment: Your explanation is not quite clear. What do you mean with *the folder path is being updated by a new log file from time to time*? Will the file be renamed? Will the folder be moved? Will a new file be created? What is it?

Comment: a new file will be created actually.

Comment: You should update your question with all needed information. Please do not add it as comments.

Comment: Thanks @olaf I got the question updated.

Comment: What other output are you expecting?

Comment: Are all the logfiles in the same folder? If so are they the only log files in that folder? If not, how do they differ naming wise from files we don't want to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the desired log file was most recently written, this might do what you want.

```
$SEL = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\log\dir' -Filter '*.log' |
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime |
    Select-Object -Last 1 |
    Select-String -Pattern 'String'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!. This is what I got and it worked as expected.

```
Invoke-Command -Computername 'servername' -ScriptBlock {$SEL = Get-ChildItem 'Filepath' | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -First 1 | Select-String -Pattern "STRING" -CaseSensitive

if ($SEL -ne $null)
{
    echo STRING found
}
else
{
    echo STRING not found
}}
```